# Can not instantiate proxy of class: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

I have a method in my repo that calls datacontext.Add method and return resutl.Entity like:

```
 var result =  _dataContext.Product.Add(product);
 await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
 return result.Entity;
```

Now I want to create mock for `EntityEntry<Product>` but I am getting an exception:

> Message: Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException
>   : Can not instantiate proxy of class:
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[[Product,
>   Product.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]. Could not find a parameterless constructor.

Here is my Test Method code:

```
 var productMock = new Mock<EntityEntry<Product>>();
 var entity = new Product{Id = 1, Name = "Bag"};
 mappingMock.Setup(m => m.Entity).Returns(entity);
 var dataContextMock = new Mock<DataContext>(_options);
 var productMockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Product>>();
 dataContextMock.Setup(a => a.Product)
     .Returns(productMockSet.Object);
 dataContextMock.Setup(m => m.Product.Add(It.IsAny<Product>())).Returns(productMock.Object);
```

What am I doing wrong? or is there any other way to Assert EntityEntry?

Comment: That class has no parameterless constructor as stated by the error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry-1

Comment: Note also `This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.`

Comment: Trying to mock EF can be task. Consider using in-memory database

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ You are trying to integration test an external framework/library. That's not your task, EF Core has been tested by Microsoft. You should test against your own code. For integration tests, use in-memory as Nkosi said. For Unit Tests, better abstract your code. You should mock your repository, not EF Core in unit tests

Comment: Then how can I Assert my method?

Answer (score 8):

I think you are missing these mocking objects:

```
var iStateManager = new Mock<IStateManager>();
var model = new Mock<Model>();

var productEntityEntry = new Mock<EntityEntry<Product>>(
new InternalShadowEntityEntry(iStateManager.Object, new EntityType("Product", model.Object, ConfigurationSource.Convention)));

productEntityEntry.SetupGet(m=> m.Entity).Returns(entity);
```